# Camel 2.X to 3.X REST Migration

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel

I am migrating from Camel 2.X to 3.x.  Before, I used to do the following in Java DSL:

```
rest().post().route().log().convertBodyTo().process().endRest();
```

Essentially I can do anything I would normally do in a from, in a rest.  In Camel 3, I have to split the above into two configs: one rest and one from:

```
rest().post().to(“fromRoute”);
from(“fromRoute”).log().convertBodyTo().process();
```

I was having trouble finding documentation on this change and the migration page camel gives does not mention this to my knowledge.

Is the former REST route definition done in Camel 2 just not a best practice? Is splitting the routes like I did the way forward in Camel 3?  Any insight on best practices here or just the correct way to define REST endpoints in camel 3 would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Camel 3.16.0, you cannot embed routes into the REST DSL. The change was documented in the upgrade guide here:

https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-3x-upgrade-guide-3_16.html#_removed_support_for_embedded_routes

There's some brief background to the change in a Jira ticket:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-17675

The correct way to configure things is as per your code example where you link the REST DSL to a route via `direct` etc. E.g.

```
rest().post().to("direct:start");

from("direct:start").log("Got body: ${body}");
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!  That clears it up for me.  I understand why someone would want to split them as it fall in line with separation of concern, but I also feel like a lot of endpoints are very straightforward and not reusable.  This causes a lot more overhead for those use cases and imho makes the code harder to read